# Script Editor “Corrupted Dictionary”

Tags: applescript

I am trying to create an AppleScript Library on OS X Mavericks. I have saved the file into `~/Library/Script Libraries` as a script bundle; it has a correct (as far as I can tell; see below) sdef file in it, and I have set the Scripting Definition field.

However, when I try to save my script bundle, AppleScript Editor gives me the following generic error message: “The application has a corrupted dictionary.” The only way I can prevent this from occurring is to delete **all** the text from the document before saving it — if there is *anything* in there (even just a comment), AppleScript throws up the error. What is going on?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/sdef.dtd">
<dictionary>
  <suite name="Regular Expressions" code="RExp" description="Commands for working with regular expressions">
    <command name="match" code="RExpMtch" description="Gets whether or not the regular expression matches.">
      <direct-parameter type="text" description="The regular expression to match." />
      <parameter name="against" code="targ" type="text" description="The string to match the regular expression against. "/>
      <parameter name="with options" code="opts" type="expression options" optional="yes" />
      <result type="expression match" />
    </command>

    <command name="default expression options" code="DOpt">
        <result type="expression options" />
    </command>

    <class name="expression match" code="Rslt" description="The output of a match command.">
        <contents type="text" name="capture group" code="Mgrp" />
        <property type="boolean" name="success" code="OK? " access="r" />
    </class>

    <class name="expression options" code="opts">
      <property name="case sensitive" code="Case" type="boolean" access="rw" />
      <property name="single line flag" code="S\n " type="boolean" access="rw" />
      <property name="multiple line flag" code="M\n " type="boolean" access="rw" />
    </class>
  </suite>
</dictionary>
```

The above sdef code is also [Here](https://gist.github.com/wjk/7727540)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason you are getting the error is because of the malformed command;

```
< command name="default expression options" code="DOpt">
            <result type="expression options" />
</command>
```

removing it allows the script to compile.

Also you should not use all lower case codes. they are reserved for Apple's codes and may clash

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, why was that command invalid in the first place?

Comment: Because it only has a 4 digit code. Commands must have 8. You should watch:https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/index.php?id=416. Also  there may be other problems..